# Was it significant and logical that the Koran was revealed to someone who could not read or write?

Tags: prophet-muhammad

So our Islamiyat teacher gave us this question for homework. In my opinion, I don't think it would have made a big difference either way, since Allah would be making all the decisions himself and would be giving commands. It would have been astonishing and difficult for even an educated man to anticipate something of such great power but since Allah gave him the "ability" to witness him, it does't matter.

Comment: Did you read [this](http://quran.com/29/45-51). What are your thoughts?

Comment: oh, yeah, seemingly it is a related reference. Well done Mrs. Azam.

Comment: @azam excellent reference, thank you. I'd suggest you post it as an answer so I'd accept it.

Comment: I'm a male @SEYYED___ALIالسید____علی

Comment: Uh, I do apologize, since one of my cousin's name as a female is azam(اعظم), then I reckoned all of..., Sorry for I do regret. Good luck mate.

Answer (score 2):

The prophet was illiterate ,and this is significant because he was not able to read books of Jews nor Christians yet he told them many things about laws of their doctrines and what they did hide from their people

Answer (score 1):

The logic behind this is to confirm the authenticity of Quran. If Muhammad (S.A.W) had been a poet or if he could read or write, People would say that Quran is also written by him. And this is to prove that Quran is from Allah(S.W.T) which knows everything towards His Servant which could not read or write. @Ahmed Hassan has also explained a good point. The **Orientalists** today say that:

> Muhammad (S.A.W) used to study Bible and older books deeply during his stay in the cave.

Muhammad (S.A.W) could not read proves that the Prophet did not study those books as He could not read.

Another point is that Muhammad (S.A.W) is the role model for all humanity. The fact that He could not read motivates illiterate people of today that they can follow Islam and the community of Islam has a good support for them unlike other communities where they are considered inferior.

Moreover, Allah (S.W.T) knows the best as Muhammad was His servant.

Comment: @DaBaws Always welcome.